# Get data from last 48 hours - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have an sql query and I need to get the count from the last 48 hours.

sql query

```
SELECT count(*), created
AS countMeta
FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
GROUP BY created > DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

I tried this query but it's not working, can someone tell me how to fix it or how to do it from scratch please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `created` is a timestamp field and you want to count all rows created in the last 48 hours, your query should be written as this:

```
select
  count(*) AS countMeta
from
  mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
where
  created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
```

If you want to show the count of every hour in the last 48 hours, one way is this:

```
select
  date_format(created, '%Y/%m/%d %h') as day_hour_created,
  count(*)
from
  mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
where
  created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
group by
  date_format(created, '%Y/%m/%d %h')
```

using the string function `date_format` we can extract only the day and hour information from the `created` field, and group by this string. Then you might also want to change the condition

```
created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
```

to this:

```
created > date_format(now()- interval 48 hour, '%Y/%m/%d %h')
```

to skip the minute and second part, in order to make the first hour complete.

Comment: It works but for some reason the result that I get are the count from the last 48 hours and the count for everything else. Is there a way to print only the count for the last 48 hours?

Comment: @user8269171 this query, unlike others, will return just the count for the last 48 hours

Comment: oh true, sorry for bothering you. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Sorry again. Do you know a way to show count for every hour in the last 48 hours?

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: I am noticing now that when I do this query:
`SELECT count(*), date_format(created, '%H:%i - %d/%m/%y') as datecreated
FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
where created > NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR
GROUP BY HOUR(created)
ORDER BY created ASC` 
the result I get is this:
`'1277','05:20 - 09/07/17'
'987','12:20 - 09/07/17'
'755','15:00 - 08/07/17'
'616','09:20 - 09/07/17'
'379','06:00 - 09/07/17'
'343','16:20 - 08/07/17'
'313','11:40 - 09/07/17'
'131','07:20 - 09/07/17'`
Do you know why are data from today missing?

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysql `DATE_SUB()` instead of `DATE()` function to get the records of last 48 hours

```
SELECT count(*), created
AS countMeta
FROM mimesi_indexer.meta_served_clips
GROUP BY created > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR)
```

Comment: It works but for some reason the result that I get are the count from the last 48 hours and the count for everything else. Is there a way to print only the count for the last 48 hours?